# How to connect to specific Wifi Access Point without disabling others?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an application that needs to connect to a specific Wifi Access Point "Network A" for an activity, then switch back to some other unknown user access point for general Internet access.

Currently, I am can achieve this by enabling Network A and disabling the rest:

```
wifiManager.enableNetwork(NETWORK_A, true);
```

But then I have to externally keep track of other networks that were previously enabled and re-enable them when this activity is complete.

Is there some way to connect to a specific network without disabling the rest?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove your network after work is done using `removeNetwork`
Android will connect back to previously connected network if it is still around.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I have it implemented. But I still have to maintain a list of previously enabled Wifi networks. I don't want to do that, but maybe that is as good as it gets..